# GUI apps always generate Xlib: extension "RANDR" missing on display ":0.0".

Tags: drivers, nvidia, video

For a long time, I've had the following show up every time I launch a GUI application from the terminal:

```
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":0.0".
```

I've had this forever and I've also had some odd edge issues forever (Unity not working particularly well, for instance) so I'm wondering if it's indicative of a greater issue with my setup. What might cause this, and at the very least, how might I suppress it?

I'm running 11.10 and this is what lspci says about my video card:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation G98 [GeForce 8400 GS] (rev a1)
```

Comment: This is a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/157319

Comment: Why was this closed as off-topic? It actually receives a high google ranking for most of my searches for the same problem. Doesn't it make sense to have an answer here?

Answer (score -1):

you have `xinerama` enabled . . .  i guess . . .then `xrandr` is not available . .  switch to `twinview`

Comment: Twinview, as far as I can tell, just doubles the display, which doesn't really do what I want :(